# regular expression for web url

Tags: regex

I am using a regular expression for validation web url. that is not validating more than one dots(.) like www.gmail.....com, other than this it is working fine.can any body update my regular expression-

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$
```

Comment: Which language/regex facility?

Comment: You should change `web url` to `domain name`

Comment: URL's can contain a _lot_ of characters. Not only `a-z`. Characters like `ü` could appear, too. And you should match case-insensitive instead of using `com|COM` (think about `cOM` or `Com`, which are valid, too).

Comment: Your top-level domain part needs to account for the many country codes (.uk, .es, .us, .ca, .au and the 200-odd others) as well as other TLDs like .info, .tv, .museum... there are loads! You'd be best just using [a-z]{2,6} (as far as I know, no TLDs use numbers or other characters).

Comment: @Nathan, there are a number of internationalized TLDs which include non-alpha characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Internationalized_country_code_top-level_domains

Comment: @eyelidlessness, Oh yes, they came in recently didn't they. Well I have no idea how you check for them!

Comment: @Nathan, you check for valid IRIs according to RFC 3987: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url/190405#190405

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE. Note this is not foolproof by any means.

`^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$`

The `+` tells the regex to match one or more times

Comment: This doesn't take into account country codes, and the many other top-level domains.

Comment: I'm modifying the OPs regex to meet their stated requirements.

Comment: You are almost on to something. The first `\.` doesn't belong.

Comment: @Marcelo True, hadn't spotted that. It shouldn't have been there in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

For Perl-compatible regex syntax, you can do this:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9-]|\.(?!\.))+\.(com|...
```

Also, this is very US-centric. My company's domain ends in `.com.au`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `+`?
`[\.]+` could be matched with one more `.`!